# Sign in with google jmtere

Tags: jmeter, google-signin

My web application has google based sing in to load dashboard ,

I tried a various method like a sign in using .p12 key, but still no success, I might be missing some key configuration,

How can I bypass or authenticate ?

Comment: Read your Google license agreement regarding the use of automated tools against their interfaces.  The only ones allowed/licensed for use are the official google supported web services interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your application expects so called [Bearer Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) which can be obtained via [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) flow.

The flow will be different depending on your application setup (web server, installed, client-side, service account) so you need to figure out what is your application setup and configure JMeter accordingly.

If the token has more or less long life time you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or any other sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and add the relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for example JMeter configuration to deal with different OAuth authentication challenges.